# Эффект фона при прокрутке страницы jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите кто знает, как называется эффект передвижения фона при прокрутке страницы как тут (середина и низ) http://livedemo00.template-help.com/muse_53463/index.html

Comment: Параллакс (parallax)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/141687/

Comment: пример на css - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/hmah1nLe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот эффект называется [parallax scrolling](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parallax%20scrolling)